# Custom PHP extension on Windows Azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure, php-extension

I have created a web app (php + mysql) in Azure by following this tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/

I am trying to install a custom PHP extension and found another tutorial from Microsoft which says it is not possible to install them.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlining/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Problem is, above tutorial is talking about "Configure" page as shown in point 3 in above URL but this link is no where to be found in Azure control panel. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI I think this is related to SaaS. But I want to implement it as PaaS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are referring to was written in 2012 and hence is showing the older Azure portal. (manage.windowsazure.com)
If you are using the new portal which is "portal.azure.com", then you will find these same settings under your azure web app -> All settings -> Application settings.